# At what cache size (chrome's browser cache) do evictions start happening?

Tags: android, google-chrome, caching, browser, evict

I'm trying to gain deeper insight into chrome's disk cache and its eviction policy. While I know that chrome uses LRU (with reuse and age taken into account) as the eviction algorithm, I can't find any resource for *when* it decides to evict an entry.

I have tried loading Alexa-top-1000 websites (on an android phone) and observed that around 100 Mbs of cache size, the rate of increase of the cache size decreases a lot. One possible argument could be that a lot of those websites were dynamic so not a lot of cachable objects. But I think what is happening is that at around that size, the cache evicts old entries and swaps them out for the new objects written to cache. But I don't know how to confirm it.
I also couldn't figure out any way to see what entries are cached on chrome (android) so that I could tell what was being evicted. If I can somehow do this, the insights will be much clearer.